# How to pass URI as parameter into worklight adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am looking to pass the URI as parameter to a worklight adapter that converts the JSON to a SOAP request. Unfortunately I could not pass the URI since it has some chunks of data. Is there another way I can pass the long string with special characters as parameter to an adapter?

URL to hit the adapter: `https://hostname:port/worklight/invoke?adapter=adaptername&procedure=procdurename&parameters=["URI with special characters"]`

Error Output:

> {"errors":["I O: String not terminated on line 1, column 15"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}

Comment: any reason you cant escape the uri before calling the prodedure

Comment: tried encoding the URI with encodeURIComponent function before I pass it to the procedure and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in worklight.properties add the the URI like

```
URI=URI-Value
```

Example:

```
LOGINHELPCONTENTURLEN = /wps/wcm/connect/GRS-EnglishLibrary/......
```

In your Adapter JS:

```
var uri = WL.Server.configuration["URI"];
```

In your invocation:

```
https://hostname:port/worklight/invoke?adapter=adaptername&procedure=procdurename&parameters=[uri]
```